# How to filter array of object based on a key pair value in object of object?

Tags: reactjs

countryList is an array of objects of country. How do I filter the objects in **countryList** based on the whether "title" value in **secondCountryList** matches the "label" in **countryList**. If the value in countryList matches the "title" in secondCountryList, then filter out the object in countryList.

```
const countryList = [
    {
        label: 'Brazil',
        value: 1,
    },
    {
        label: 'Peru',
        value: 2,
    },
    {
        label: 'New York',
        value: 3,
    },
    {
        label: 'Seattle',
        value: 4,
    },
    {
        label: 'Indonesia',
        value: 5,
    },
]
```

```
const secondCountryList = {
    "195": {
        "id": 195,
        "title": "Brazil",
    },
    "198": {
        "id": 198,
        "title": "Peru",
    },
    "345": {
        "id": 345,
        "title": "Poland",
    },
    "56": {
        "id": 56,
        "title": "Mexico",
    },
    "90": {
        "id": 90,
        "title": "Thailand",
    }
}
```

Example output after filtering, since Brazil and Peru was found in secondCountryList.

```
const countryList = [
    {
        label: 'New York',
        value: 3,
    },
    {
        label: 'Seattle',
        value: 4,
    },
    {
        label: 'Indonesia',
        value: 5,
    },
]
```

Comment: Have you tried to implement any such function? If yes, could you update your question with your approach. And let us know if you're facing any errors. We can help you debug it.

Comment: As a suggestion, you could try to extract the "title" from `secondCountryList` and create an array of titles. Then loop over those to find out if it exists as label in `countryList` array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
 Simple solution 
 
 const countryList = [
        {
            label: 'Brazil',
            value: 1,
        },
        {
            label: 'Peru',
            value: 2,
        },
        {
            label: 'New York',
            value: 3,
        },
        {
            label: 'Seattle',
            value: 4,
        },
        {
            label: 'Indonesia',
            value: 5,
        },
    ];
    
      const secondCountryList = {
        "195": {
            "id": 195,
            "title": "Brazil",
        },
        "198": {
            "id": 198,
            "title": "Peru",
        },
        "345": {
            "id": 345,
            "title": "Poland",
        },
        "56": {
            "id": 56,
            "title": "Mexico",
        },
        "90": {
            "id": 90,
            "title": "Thailand",
        }
    };

let filteredListOfCountries = countryList;

for (const key in secondCountryList) {
    countryList.forEach(value=>{ 
    if(value.label === secondCountryList[key].title) 
        filteredListOfCountries = filteredListOfCountries.filter(value => value.label !=        secondCountryList[key].title)
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array.filter`, `Object.keys`, and `Arrays.map`:

```
const countryList = [
    {
        label: 'Brazil',
        value: 1,
    },
    {
        label: 'Peru',
        value: 2,
    },
    {
        label: 'New York',
        value: 3,
    },
    {
        label: 'Seattle',
        value: 4,
    },
    {
        label: 'Indonesia',
        value: 5,
    },
]

const secondCountryList = {
    "195": {
        "id": 195,
        "title": "Brazil",
    },
    "198": {
        "id": 198,
        "title": "Peru",
    },
    "345": {
        "id": 345,
        "title": "Poland",
    },
    "56": {
        "id": 56,
        "title": "Mexico",
    },
    "90": {
        "id": 90,
        "title": "Thailand",
    }
}

// This makes exclusionList an array of strings
const exclusionList = Object.keys(secondCountryList).map((key) => (secondCountryList[key].title))

// Then you can use the exclusionList to filter out the first array
const filteredCountryList = countryList.filter((country) => !exclusionList.includes(country.label))

/*
Should be:
const countryList = [
    {
        label: 'New York',
        value: 3,
    },
    {
        label: 'Seattle',
        value: 4,
    },
    {
        label: 'Indonesia',
        value: 5,
    },
]
*/
console.log("filteredCountryList", filteredCountryList)
```